# Python Twitter Filter and Collecting Tweets

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I'm working on a Natural Language Processing project now but I'm stuck at the beginning about collecting tweets in a specific language.

I'm trying to use tweepy library with python but this code is not giving any returns on console

Where I'm doing wrong?

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time
import json

# authentication data- get this info from twitter after you create your application
ckey="*****"
csecret="*****"
atoken="*****"
asecret="*****"

# define listener class
class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            print (data)   # write the whole tweet to terminal
            return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print('failed on data, ', str(e)) # if there is an error, show what it is
            time.sleep(5)  # one error could be that you're rate-limited; this will cause the script to pause for 5 seconds

    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)

# authenticate yourself
auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(languages=['tr'])  # track what you want to search for!
```

Comment: as an advice, never post keys online even if they are mock keys because someone could impersonate you by using those

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and received a 406 error which per the [API](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes) which means the query is not an acceptable request. After adding a track term parameter in the filter method it works fine. I believe this is a limitation of the API itself. See also [406 error in Streaming API when filtering on language](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/291).

Comment: even with track parameter it is not printing any results from request istill dont know how to print

Comment: First I would remove your API keys from your initial question. Second I ran your code using my credentials and it worked fine. Are any error codes printing for you?

Comment: it is not even giving any responses, even with track parameter. it is just working, not even debugging.

Comment: Try generating new API keys.

Answer (score 0):

For example, I want to search 10000 tweets containing the word "#tennis" and print tweet text and authors

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
TestTweet = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="#tennis").items(10000)

while True:
  try:
      tweet = TestTweet.next()
      print(str(tweet.author.screen_name))
      print(tweet.text)

 except tweepy.error.TweepError:
      print "Twitter rate limit, need to wait 15 min"
      time.sleep(60 * 16)
      continue
 except StopIteration:
      break
```

if you wanna search by user's name

```
tweet = api.get_status(id=user_name)
test_text = tweet.text
test_user = tweet.user.screen_name
```